# 'Compressing' input of 2D array of character data in C

Tags: c, char, compression, multidimensional-array

this program is trying to read in a 2D array (5x10) of char, and compress them. Such that (aaacccfeee -> a3c3f1e3). I have some trouble with my output, and I can't figure out where's the problem.

Here's the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h> 
#define SIZE1 5 
#define SIZE2 10

void compress(char data[SIZE1][SIZE2]);

int main ()
{
    int row, col;
    char qn2[SIZE1][SIZE2];

    printf("\nEnter your data (5x10 of characters): \n");
    for (row = 0; row < SIZE1; ++row)
        for (col = 0; col < SIZE2; ++col)
            scanf("%c", &qn2[row][col]);
    fflush(stdin);
    compress(qn2);
    return 0;
}

void compress(char data[SIZE1][SIZE2])
{
    int row, col, count = 0;
    char tempChar = data[0][0];

    printf("\nThe compression output: \n");

    for (row = 0; row < SIZE1; row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < SIZE2; col++)
        {
            if (data[row][col] == tempChar)
            {
                count ++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c%d", tempChar, count);
                tempChar = data[row][col];
                count = 1;
            }   
        } printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Expected output:

```
Enter your data (5x10 of characters):
aaacccdeee
fffggghiii
jjjkkklmmm
nnnooopqqq
rrrssstuuu

The compression output:
a3c3d1e3
f3g3h1i3
j3k3l1m3
n3o3p1q3
r3s3t1u3
```

Output I got instead:

```
The compression output:
a3c3d1
e3f3g3h1
i3j3k3l1
m3n3o3p1
q3r3s3t1u3
```

Comment: Duh. sry about the false alarm. You need to prepend your `%c` with leading whitespace if you want the newlines consumed during scanning. Try `" %c"`. (again, sry, that decl looked odd until i saw it closer). But the `fflush` is still non-standard.

Comment: The code seems ok except the part with scanf

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig That helps in getting rid of the whitespace. But I need to display it such that: the result of every new row must be displayed on a new line.

Comment: @unintendedjoy ok. so you need something like `"%c %d ", tempChar, count` for your `printf` params, and slipping  a `printf("\n")` or `puts("")` just *after* the closing `}` of your `for-col` loop, (dumping any char/count you have left, btw) I'm not sure exactly what output your looking for, but that would seem pretty close to what you seek. Play around with it anyway.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm sorry but I can't seem to get it. I placed printf("\n"); after the for-col loop, but I don't get the expected output as shown above (I edited the question to show you an example of the expected output).

Comment: You may as well also update your posted code to include where you put the `printf("\n")` because the output you're showing indicates you put it after the for-**row** loop; not the for-col loop.

Comment: @WhozCraig Okay, I edited where I placed my printf("\n"); and also the output I got from it.

Comment: yeah, that would be the final piece. you're not cleaning up the last token from the line i.e. if you finish with i3, you're not going to emit it until something other than `i` comes along, but that won't happen until the next line. before that `printf('\n')` dump whatever is in `tempChar` and `count`. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (row = 0; row < SIZE1; row++)
{
    for (col = 0; col < SIZE2; col++)
    {
        if (data[row][col] == tempChar)
        {
            count ++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", tempChar);
            printf("%d", count);
            tempChar = data[row][col];
            count = 1;
        }   
    }
}
if(count!=0) //need to print the last sequence of repeated characters.
{
     printf("%c", tempChar);
     printf("%d", count);
}
```

Comment: @valter even if it is 1 you need to print the value.

Comment: Why do you keep the if statement then?

Comment: @valter it's not exactly required in the context of this question. But, then adding checks is always good if there is some change later on in the problem statement.